# fwsnort won't apply rules in iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, debian-jessie, snort

I'm using Debian 8, and I want to update fwsnort rules through this command:

```
fwsnort --update-rules
```

Though after downloading 9.4 MB of rules in '/etc/fwsnort/snort_rules/emerging-all.rules' file, it fails to apply all rules in iptables through this command:

```
fwsnort --ipt-apply
```

and gives the error:

> [+] Splicing fwsnort 11312 rules into the iptables policy...
>   iptables-restore v1.4.21: invalid port/service '[6789]' specified
>   Error occurred at line: 11131
>   Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

and even when I try to directly restore all rules from emerging-all.rules back into iptables by using this command:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/fwsnort/snort_rules/emerging-all.rules
```

it results this output:

```
iptables-restore: line 53 failed
```

What's the problem with fwsnort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is [a small but severe bug in fwsnort](https://bugs.debian.org/860164) (even in the current upstream version 1.6.6), which causes one of the rules (at least the rules as currently online) to cause a syntax error. This only happens if a single port is specified in a snort rule in brackets as fwsnort only removes the brackets if there's more than one port is specified.

[This patch applied to the Debian package](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/fwsnort.git/tree/debian/patches/fix-dport-bracket-usage.patch) (currently only in Debian Unstable) fixes this issue.

I also [submitted the patch I used to fix the issue in Debian as pull request](https://github.com/mrash/fwsnort/pull/14) at upstream. Upstream reacted promptly and released [fwsnort 1.6.7 with that fix](https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwsnort/download/).

Comment: thanks for details, what's wrong with Debian? first SELinux and then fwsnort. I think not having a firewall would not be wise on Linux, would you suggest a firewall for Debian 8 and CentOS 7 pls?

Comment: No idea what you mean with "what's wrong with Debian?". fwsnort did not break only in Debian but upstream and hence in all distributions. Debian is the distribution which brought up the fix. And IMHO at least SElinux is not a firewall. (Not sure if fwsnort could be called a firewall.) Regarding firewalls: IMHO there's usually no need for a firewall. Just keeping your system up-to-date with security updates and configuring access to services provided by the system properly (in the server application) usually suffices way more than hiding problems behind blocking access on the network side.

Comment: again thanks for explaining firewalls and clearing this up 'cause I was blaming Debian :) and my apology about giving wrong info about SElinux, I had a problem installing it on my system, it's solved now, nothing wrong with its package.